# hide cursor mac os yosemite

Tags: macos, cursor-position

How do I hide my cursor "at will" in Mac OS 10.10 Yosemite? On Mavericks I used [Cursorcerer](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25355/cursorcerer). But I think the app is no longer compatable. Is their an alternative?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Try apple.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cursorcerer now works in Yosemite: http://doomlaser.com/cursorcerer-hide-your-cursor-at-will

Comment: I guess in the end patience was the answer :)

Comment: No it doesn't work (osx 10.11.6)

Comment: It still works in macOS 10.12 Sierra